# Renaming index values in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Creating my dataframe:

```
from pandas import *
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = zip(*arrays)

index = MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first','second'])
data = DataFrame(randn(8,2),index=index,columns=['c1','c2'])

data
Out[68]: 
                    c1        c2
first second                    
bar   one     0.833816 -1.529639
      two     0.340150 -1.818052
baz   one    -1.605051 -0.917619
      two    -0.021386 -0.222951
foo   one     0.143949 -0.406376
      two     1.208358 -2.469746
qux   one    -0.345265 -0.505282
      two     0.158928  1.088826
```

I would like to rename the "first" index values, such as "bar"->"cat", "baz"->"dog", etc.  However, every example I have read either operates on a single-level index and/or loops through the entire index to effectively re-create it from scratch.  I was thinking something like:

```
data = data.reindex(index={'bar':'cat','baz':'dog'})
```

but this does not work, nor do I really expect it to work on multiple indexes.  Can I do such a replacement without looping through the entire dataframe index?

***Begin edit***

I am hesitant to update to 0.13 until release, so I used the following workaround:

```
index = data.index.tolist()
for r in xrange( len(index) ):
    index[r] = (codes[index[r][0]],index[r][1])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index,names=data.index.names)
data.index = index
```

Where  is a previous defined dictionary of code:string pairs.  This actually isn't as big of a performance his as I was expecting (takes a couple seconds to operate over ~1.1 million rows).  It is not as pretty as a one-liner, but it does work.

***End Edit***

Comment: This is currently an enhancement proposal for a future version of pandas: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4160 (@unutbu soln works ATM though)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `set_levels` method ([new in version 0.13.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#what-s-new)):

```
data.index.set_levels([[u'cat', u'dog', u'foo', u'qux'], 
                       [u'one', u'two']], inplace=True)
```

yields

```
                    c1        c2
first second                    
cat   one    -0.289649 -0.870716
      two    -0.062014 -0.410274
dog   one     0.030171 -1.091150
      two     0.505408  1.531108
foo   one     1.375653 -1.377876
      two    -1.478615  1.351428
qux   one     1.075802  0.532416
      two     0.865931 -0.765292
```

---

To remap a level based on a dict, you could use a function such as this:

```
def map_level(df, dct, level=0):
    index = df.index
    index.set_levels([[dct.get(item, item) for item in names] if i==level else names
                      for i, names in enumerate(index.levels)], inplace=True)

dct = {'bar':'cat', 'baz':'dog'}
map_level(data, dct, level=0)
```

---

Here's a runnable example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = zip(*arrays)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first','second'])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,2),index=index,columns=['c1','c2'])
data2 = data.copy()

data.index.set_levels([[u'cat', u'dog', u'foo', u'qux'], 
                       [u'one', u'two']], inplace=True)
print(data)
#                     c1        c2
# first second                    
# cat   one     0.939040 -0.748100
#       two    -0.497006 -1.185966
# dog   one    -0.368161  0.050339
#       two    -2.356879 -0.291206
# foo   one    -0.556261  0.474297
#       two     0.647973  0.755983
# qux   one    -0.017722  1.364244
#       two     1.007303  0.004337

def map_level(df, dct, level=0):
    index = df.index
    index.set_levels([[dct.get(item, item) for item in names] if i==level else names
                      for i, names in enumerate(index.levels)], inplace=True)
dct = {'bar':'wolf', 'baz':'rabbit'}
map_level(data2, dct, level=0)
print(data2)
#                      c1        c2
# first  second                    
# wolf   one     0.939040 -0.748100
#        two    -0.497006 -1.185966
# rabbit one    -0.368161  0.050339
#        two    -2.356879 -0.291206
# foo    one    -0.556261  0.474297
#        two     0.647973  0.755983
# qux    one    -0.017722  1.364244
#        two     1.007303  0.004337
```

Comment: 0.13 is still in development, I'm still running 0.12.0.  Is there any indication regarding the stability of 0.13x?  
I don't see much documentation for .index.set_levels.  In the example above, setting levels is simple since we have only two levels.  Can a dictionary be passed to replace only values in one index without touching (or having to specify values for) the other axes?

Comment: Works fine for me in 0.16.2, and 0.18.1

Answer (score 2):

The `set_levels` method was causing my new column names to be out of order. So I found a different solution that isn't very clean, but works well. The method is to `print df.index` (or equivalently `df.columns`) and then copy and paste the output with the desired values changed. For example:

```
print data.index
```

> MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']], labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
>              names=['first', 'second'])

```
data.index = MultiIndex(levels=[['new_bar', 'new_baz', 'new_foo', 'new_qux'],
                                ['new_one', 'new_two']],
                        labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
                        names=['first', 'second'])
```

We can have full control over names by editing the labels as well. For example:

```
data.index = MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'],
                                ['one', 'twooo', 'three', 'four',
                                 'five', 'siz', 'seven', 'eit']],
                        labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]],
                        names=['first', 'second'])
```

Note that in this example we have already done something like `from pandas import MultiIndex` or `from pandas import *`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with set_levels putting the new column names out of order. I think it is putting the new column names based on the prior "labels" parameter of the MultiIndex. Nice workaround.