# rename columns function not working in pandas

Tags: pandas, rename

I have a dataframe of tuples columns that I'm trying to rename.

Here is the `.info()`:

```
session_deciles.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 5 columns):
(session_deciles, , )         10 non-null category
(total_sessions, , sum)       10 non-null int64
(POLL, sum, sum)              10 non-null int64
(PANELIST_COUNT, sum, sum)    10 non-null float64
(VIDEO_USED, sum, sum)        10 non-null int64
dtypes: category(1), float64(1), int64(3)
memory usage: 490.0 bytes
```

When I do something like this:

```
session_deciles.rename(columns={ ('VIDEO_USED','sum','sum') : 'total_sessions'},inplace=True)
```

nothing happens (not even an error message). In fact, I can do something like this:

```
session_deciles.rename(columns={ ('FAKE COLUMN NAME','sum','sum') : 'total_sessions'},inplace=True)
```

and I still won't get an error message.

There aren't any spaces:

```
session_deciles.columns.tolist()
Out[47]:
[('session_deciles', '', ''),
('total_sessions', '', 'sum'),
('POLL', 'sum', 'sum'),
('PANELIST_COUNT', 'sum', 'sum'),
('VIDEO_USED', 'sum', 'sum')]

In [58]:

session_deciles.columns[4]
Out[58]:
('VIDEO_USED', 'sum', 'sum')
```

now this is strange:

This

```
session_deciles.rename(columns={session_deciles.columns[2] : 'test_column'},inplace=True)
```

doesn't do anything.

```
session_deciles
Out[108]:
     session_deciles    total_sessions  POLL    PANELIST_COUNT  VIDEO_USED
                                         sum    sum             sum
                         sum             sum    sum             sum 
0   (0, 1]               1286            55     389             1133
1   (1, 2]               2056            102    784             1833
```

But this:

```
session_deciles.rename(columns={session_deciles.columns[2]**[1]** : 'test_column'},inplace=True)
```

returns this:

```
  session_deciles   total_sessions  POLL    PANELIST_COUNT  VIDEO_USED
                                    test_column  test_column test_column
                                    test_column  test_column test_column    
0   (0, 1]               1286           55           389          1133
1   (1, 2]               2056           102          784          1833
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, when I create a df using your list of column names and call `rename` it works:`In [7]:

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[('session_deciles', '', ''),
('total_sessions', '', 'sum'),
('POLL', 'sum', 'sum'),
('PANELIST_COUNT', 'sum', 'sum'),
('VIDEO_USED', 'sum', 'sum')])
In [8]:

df.rename(columns={('PANELIST_COUNT', 'sum', 'sum'):'new_col'}, inplace=True)
df
Out[8]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(session_deciles, , ), (total_sessions, , sum), (POLL, sum, sum), new_col, (VIDEO_USED, sum, sum)]
Index: []`

Comment: see above for some wacky behavior when trying to pass the column index

Comment: Renaming a multi-index is not supported at the moment (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4160). @EdChum the reason it works for you is because it are tuples, not a MultiIndex due to the way you created it.

Comment: @joris that's interesting, is it not possible to use `set_levels`?

Comment: I would do `index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(...)` to make up a dataframe in this case. `set_levels` would be possible to rename, but with that it is not possible to rename only a single value, you have to specify all elements of a level

Comment: @joris yes I can see that this would be a pain to do for just a single value

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529619/renaming-index-values-in-multiindex-dataframe

Comment: @joris is correct. it's a multi-index created after multiple groupbys on a dataframe.  `.droplevel(1)` worked for me. once i have one level i can rename as i want